# Simple SwiftUI List example. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: swiftui

I'm having problems binding string data to a a Text inside a list. Not sure exactly what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's a simple fix. When you pass an array to `List`, the elements in the array need to conform to the `Identifiable` protocol. `String` does not conform to `Identifiable`, so the way to make this work is to use `.identified(by:)` like so:

```swift
struct StringList: View {
    let strings = ["1234", "5678"]

    var body: some View {
        List(strings.identified(by: \.self)) { string in
            Text(string)
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use a `ForEach` inside `List`:

```swift
struct StringList: View {
    let strings = ["1234", "5678"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(strings.identified(by: \.self)) { string in
                Text(string)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these examples achieve the same output, but the first one is cleaner and requires less code.

## Update

As of Xcode Beta 4, `identified(by:)` has been deprecated in favor of specific initializers for `List` and `ForEach`:

```swift
struct StringList: View {
    let strings = ["1234", "5678"]

    var body: some View {
        List(strings, id: \.self) { string in
            Text(string)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct StringList: View {
    let strings = ["1234", "5678"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { string in
                Text(string)
            }
        }
    }
}
```